# Install odl-restconf in custom karaf distribution

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, karaf, opendaylight

I have a custom karaf installation. I want to do a feature:install odl-restconf.
for doing this i have done a feature:repo-add of feature file available in the below location https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/org/opendaylight/controller/features-restconf/1.3.0-SNAPSHOT/
After this i have made entries in karaf org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg file and added the below url as part of maven repo
http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories@id=public, \
    http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories@id=opendaylight.snapshot, \

While doing a feature:install it is not checking this url. It tries to download it from some other location.

```
2016-02-27 21:21:19,451 | INFO  | nsole user karaf | FeaturesServiceImpl              | 9 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 4.0.3 | Adding features: odl-restconf/[1.3.0.SNAPSHOT,1.3.0.SNAPSHOT]
2016-02-27 21:21:27,754 | WARN  | ool-146-thread-1 | AetherBasedResolver              | 5 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.8.4 | Error resolving artifactorg.opendaylight.controller:sal-rest-connector:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT:Could not find artifact org.opendaylight.controller:sal-rest-connector:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT in apache (http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/)
shaded.org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.opendaylight.controller:sal-rest-connector:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT in apache (http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/)
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:573)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:528)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:506)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:481)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadTask.download(MavenDownloadTask.java:34)[9:org.apache.karaf.features.core:4.0.3]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.run(AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.java:58)[9:org.apache.karaf.features.core:4.0.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: shaded.org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.opendaylight.controller:sal-rest-connector:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT in apache (http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/)
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:39)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    ... 16 more
2016-02-27 21:21:49,757 | WARN  | ool-146-thread-1 | AetherBasedResolver              | 5 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.8.4 | Error resolving artifactorg.opendaylight.controller:sal-rest-connector:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT:Could not find artifact org.opendaylight.controller:sal-rest-connector:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT in apache (http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/)
shaded.org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.opendaylight.controller:sal-rest-connector:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT in apache (http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/)
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:573)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:528)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:506)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:481)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadTask.download(MavenDownloadTask.java:34)[9:org.apache.karaf.features.core:4.0.3]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.run(AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.java:58)[9:org.apache.karaf.features.core:4.0.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: shaded.org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.opendaylight.controller:sal-rest-connector:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT in apache (http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/)
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:39)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    ... 16 more
2016-02-27 21:22:11,340 | WARN  | ool-146-thread-1 | AetherBasedResolver              | 5 - org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api - 1.8.4 | Error resolving artifactorg.opendaylight.controller:sal-rest-connector:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT:Could not find artifact org.opendaylight.controller:sal-rest-connector:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT in apache (http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/)
shaded.org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.opendaylight.controller:sal-rest-connector:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT in apache (http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/)
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:573)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:528)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:506)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.internal.AetherBasedResolver.resolve(AetherBasedResolver.java:481)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.MavenDownloadTask.download(MavenDownloadTask.java:34)[9:org.apache.karaf.features.core:4.0.3]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.download.impl.AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.run(AbstractRetryableDownloadTask.java:58)[9:org.apache.karaf.features.core:4.0.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: shaded.org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.opendaylight.controller:sal-rest-connector:jar:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT in apache (http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/)
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:39)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)[4:org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn:2.4.3]
    ... 16 more
```

My aim is to install odl-restconf if some other way is there please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To declare a snapshots repository, you should add `@snapshots` (the `.snapshot` in your example are not taken into account to determine if a repository can contain snapshots):

```
http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories@id=public, \
http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories@id=opendaylight@snapshots, \
```