# How to install opendaylight restconf

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf, opendaylight

Anybody know how to install opendaylight restconf in a custom karaf distribution. I tried adding the rest conf feature repo and tried to do a feature install. But this will fail by saying odl-config-persister is missing. When you try to install odl-config-persister another error will come. Is there any other way to install opendaylight restconf in karaf.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install odl-restconf in custom karaf distribution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671915/install-odl-restconf-in-custom-karaf-distribution)

Answer (score 0):

Start Karaf and verify if you have this feature:

```
feature:list | grep 'restconf'
```

If so, you can install it, "feature:install feature-name":

```
feature:install odl-restconf-all
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you build your project, ensure **karaf/pom.xml** includes following stanza under the **dependencies** tag:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.opendaylight.l2switch</groupId>
      <artifactId>features-l2switch</artifactId>
      <version>0.7.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <classifier>features</classifier>
      <type>xml</type>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then, build your project:

```
[your_project_root]$ mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Once the build completes, start **karaf** and install **odl-l2switch-switch**.

```
[your_project_root]$ cd karaf/target/assembly/bin/
[bin]$ ./karaf
opendaylight-user@root>feature:install odl-l2switch-switch
opendaylight-user@root>
```

**odl-l2switch-switch** includes **RESTCONF** as a dependency.